# Is it possible to build protobuf without pthread?

Tags: c++, pthreads, protocol-buffers

There is a need to use Protocol Buffers on the real-time OS where there is no pthread. I am able to link protobuf statically this way

```
g++ -g -Wall example.pb.cc example.cc -o example -static -lprotobuf -lpthread
```

However without pthread I get link errors. Is it possible to configure protobuf to work without pthread?

Comment: Weird. Does the documentation indicate what pthreads are used for?

Comment: No. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) tell nothing about pthreads. 

Without pthreads I see a bunch of errors like that:

>`/home/ghost/protobuf-2.4.1/src/./google/protobuf/stubs/once.h:115: undefined reference to 'pthread_once'
/`

Comment: Note that some of the [alternative implementations](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns), such as protobuf-c and nanopb, do work without pthread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really. See [this](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=248) unresolved issue.

Someone has patched an older protobuf version to not depend on pthreads, see [here](http://arachnism.blogspot.no/2010/03/compiling-google-protobuf-without.html) - which you might take a look at if you really need it, and possibly forward port.

Also note that you're supposed to use pkg_config to get the proper compiler and linker flags when using protobuf, e.g.

```
pkg-config --cflags protobuf         # compiler flags
pkg-config --libs protobuf           # linker flags
```